# Rearranging nested strucutre into cell array in MATLAB

Tags: arrays, matlab, nested, structure

I have a nested strucutre array that i want to rearrange into one big cell array. The sturcture looks as follows

- 1st level: 
  EpochedAll    1x1 strucutre
- 2nd level:    subject 
  epoched02     1x1 strucutre 
  epoched03     1x1 strucutre 
  ...           1x1 strucutre 
  epoched12     1x1 strucutre
- 3rd level:    muscle 
  ECR           1x1 strucutre 
  FCR           1x1 strucutre
- 4th level     condition 
  green         124x2 double (number of trials is different for every subject and condition) 
  red           122x2 double 
  control       105x2 double

What i want to get is a cell array that has the following columns:

value from condition  ... id of subject  ...  id of muscle  ...  id of condition

.
. 
.

I am new to MATLAB and programming in general and would appreciate any pointers or ideas from where to start

Comment: For start, what is the link between `epoched##`, `ECR/FCR`, `green/red/control` and `value`, `id_subject`, `id_muscle`, `id_cond`? What is the path to, say, `control(15,2)`? Is it `EpochedAll.epoched02.FCR.contol(15,2)` or `EpochedAll{1}{1}{2}{3}(15,2)`?

Answer (score 0):

So this rearranges the data based on the muscle:

```
names = fieldnames(epochedAll); 
mus = {'ECR','FCR'};
cond = {'green', 'red','control'};
masterArray = []

%This program will loop through each subject and the conditions of a given
%muscle (the muscle is chosen by writing either ECR or FCR in the ecrarray
%variable below. It will then concatenate all of the data from each condition of
%each patient into one master array, with numbers representing the subject
%and condition, along with the condition values.

for x = 1:length(names) 
    for z = 1: length(cond) 
        tempArray = []   
        ecrarray = epochedAll.(names{x}).ECR.(cond{z})(:,1);
        tempArray = vertcat(tempArray, ecrarray); 
        len = length(tempArray);
        column = zeros(len, 1);
        column(column == 0) = z;
        condCol = column;
        column(column == z) = x; 
        subjCol = column;
        tempArray = horzcat(tempArray, condCol, subjCol); 
        masterArray = vertcat(masterArray, tempArray);

    end
end
```

Hope this hepls someone else